# Python: Approaches to designing an event driven server

Tags: python, sockets, networking, zeromq

I'm implementing a server which works as follows:

- AddUser(content) - Adds a user to the server, responds with the User ID
- OnRegister(UserID, Connection) - Registers the client with the server to a specific UserID
- OnUserChange(UserID) - Notifies the registered clients (By the connection they've registered with) (This should not be accessible to regular clients)

So for example:
The **first** part:

- The client adds a user (using AddUser)
- The server generates the user ID '54', queues the registration task for later (Because the registration process is slow) and then responds with the user ID

The **second** part:

- The client registers with the User ID: '54' and the connection "127.0.0.1:4334" (The way it sends it is not defined yet)
- The client listens on 127.0.0.1:4334 (For the server's response)
- The server registers the User ID to the client's connection (Meanwhile it can get more requests)
- The server is notified about the users state change through a different socket asynchronously
- The server sends a response to all of the registered clients (notifiying about the state change)

The environment is Linux, the latency should be small and the data transfer size doesn't really matter.

The **question** is what's the **best approach** for this specific routine?

I've thought about three ways approaching this:

- Using a reactor based on the connection (When each connection is mapped to a given user ID except for the connection of "User changes notifications")
- Implementing a Rest API (using flask) for the client and implementing something different for the notifications on users changes
- Using a Pub-Sub pattern based on channels that's connected to a group of users (So the client first publishes the Users it subscribes for and the server responds (publishes) to the client by these user ids)

Anyway, I will be glad to hear your advice about this, and maybe a better way to approach this